# Need formula using SUMPRODUCT that bypasses #VALUE! entries

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((('Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000<=X8)*'Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000)>=W8))`

Column L is an output of dates.  X8 and W8 are dates that collectively form a range.

This formula works great if all dates are returned or if there are some blank cells in column L.  But if instead any cell in column L has code that returns #VALUE!, then the formula breaks down.

So basically, I need to modify this formula to accommodate for the fact that some cells in column L return #VALUE!.  Is there a way to overlook such cells so that the formula only handles cells that have returned actual dates?

Comment: does this formula works for you: `=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000,"<="&X8,'Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000,">="&W8)`?

Answer (score 1):

As I follow up from comments, this formula works:

```
=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000,"<="&X8,'Sheet1'!$L$2:$L$100000,">="&W8)
```